# Flash in WebView Not functioning well unless full screen

Tags: android, flash, webview, android-webview

i'm creating WebView that opens html with an embeded swf file. The WebView loads the swf game, but i cannot play unless i openned it in full screen mode.

***How can i set it to open in full screen mode automatically?***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please past your code here...

Answer (score 0):

```
webSetting.setUseWideViewPort(true)
webSetting.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)
webSetting.setDefaultZoom(...)
```

you can find analogous codes in browser application

Comment: The main problem is that i need the flash to start full screen to function is the correct way, instead of touching the screen and holding for couple of seconds and switching to the full screen.

Answer (score 0):

For mobile devices you may use the fullScreenOnSelection HTML tag. If you have an object tag, then add:

```
<param name="fullScreenOnSelection" value="true >
```

for an embed tag, add the attribute:

```
fullScreenOnSelection="true"
```

This will allow you to fullscreen on first touch. If you want to fullscreen before the user interacts with the flash content, then you can send a MotionEvent after the swf has loaded.